# Find an item and place it on my shopping cart

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, cypress

I'm learning both javascript and cypress, and I need your help, please... I want to find an item on a page, and add that item to the shoping cart.

I don't understand why I don't get any answer after `.find`. I don't get an error on cypress, but the item it's never added to the cart, and the `cy.log` dont display anyting.

```
/// <reference types="Cypress"/>

     it ('ContarElementos', () => {
        cy.visit ('https://www.saucedemo.com/v1/inventory.html')

        cy.get('.inventory_list >')
        cy.get('.inventory_list >').as ('ProductosPopulares')
        cy.get('@ProductosPopulares').should('have.length', 6)
    })

   it ('Agregar elemento "top" al carrito de compra desde la pagina principal', function (){
        cy.visit ('https://www.saucedemo.com/v1/inventory.html')

        cy.get('.inventory_list >').as ('ProductosPopulares')

        cy.get('@ProductosPopulares')
        .find ('.inventory_item_name')
        .each(($el,index,$list) => {
            if($el.attr('.inventory_item_name') == 'Sauce Labs Onesie'){
                cy.log ('Se encontró lo buscado')
                cy.get ('@ProductosPopulares').eq(index).contains('ADD TO CART').click()
            } 
        })
    })
    })
I know the place that has the item, so if I place it like this, it find appears on the cart, but I need it to work if I dont know the place on the list.

it ('Agregar elemento "top" al carrito de compra desde la pagina principal', function (){

        cy.visit ('https://www.saucedemo.com/v1/inventory.html')

        cy.get('.inventory_list >').as ('ProductosPopulares')

        cy.get('@ProductosPopulares')
        .find ('.inventory_item_name')
        .each(($el,index,$list) => {
            if($el.attr('.inventory_item_name') == 'Sauce Labs Onesie'){
                cy.log ('Se encontró lo buscado')
                
            } 
            
        })
        cy.get ('@ProductosPopulares').eq(5).contains('ADD TO CART').click()
    })
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a mix-up between text and attribute, try swapping the `.find()` command and the `.contains()` command.

Something like this:

```js
cy.contains('.inventory_list .inventory_item', 'Sauce Labs Onesie')
  .find('button:contains("ADD TO CART")').click()
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, I tried it, but didn't work, :)